# MailManager override "from" email

Tags: 8, emails

I use [MailManager](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Mail!MailManager.php/function/MailManager%3A%3Amail/8.2.x) to send emails to end users for notifications. I would like to override the email address shown to the end user, using a "fake" address shown and not the real mail account used to send the email. I use the following code, however, in my gmail receiving account I don't see the `noreply@mymailserver.com` but the real email account used.

```
$params['message'] = $message;
$params['subject'] = $title;
$key = 'send_email';
$langcode = \Drupal::currentUser()->getPreferredLangcode();
$send = true;
$result = $mailManager->mail($module, $key, $targetEmail, $langcode,
                    $params, 'noreply@mymailserver.com', $send);
```

Is there a way to define a custom address to be shown to the end user? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [hook_mail_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.api.php/function/hook_mail_alter/8.7.x) to customize the From:

```
MODULE_NAME_mail_alter($key, &$message, $params) {

  switch ($key) {
    case 'my_email_key':
      $message['headers']['From'] = 'My Email Name <my_email@address.com>';
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: That should be `MODULE_NAME_mail_alter(`

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan - I fixed it in my post.